# How to get selected tab's id and element reference in angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular5, angular7, angular8

I am trying to get selected tab's element reference but not working getting like undefined.I do not know why i am getting like this.Actually i want to get selected tab element reference name like for first tab element reference is tab1 so if i click first tab i want to get that's tab id and element reference.
Example if i click first tab alert should be "This tab id is =mytab1 and element refrerence is = tab1"

How can do it?If anyone know please help to find the solution.

app.component.html:

```
    <my-tabs (selectedTabClick)="test($event)">
      <my-tab [tabTitle]="'Tab 1'"  id="mytab1" #tab1>
        Tab 1 content
      </my-tab>
      <my-tab tabTitle="Tab 2" id="mytab2" #tab2>
        Tab 2 content
      </my-tab>
    </my-tabs>
```

Demo:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-example-egszd2?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Inside `app.component.ts`, change the method `test` as follows:

```
test(event): void {
    console.log(event.data);
    alert("This tab id is " + event.data.id + " and element reference is " + event.data);
}
```